# Can the list of dirs in the firefox "save as" dialog be changed?

Tags: linux, firefox

I have a dir where I store memes.

I would like to have it listed on the left hand side of the "save" and "open" file dialogs, as shortcuts.

The same place where "home" and "images" etc are listed.

Is it possible to add to this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  In the Save-As dialog, you can right-click on a directory and choose the "Add to Bookmarks" option from the pop-up menu.

This may vary a little depending on your desktop environment - this is how it works for me in xfce4, and I'm fairly sure it works exactly the same in gnome or mate or cinnamon.  It might be slightly different in KDE (because KDE is based on Qt, not GTK).

You can also maintain the list of "Bookmarks" in your desktop environment's file browser (e.g. I can use either `pcmanfm` or `thunar` file browsers in xfce to add or remove items from the bookmarks list, or rename them, or change the order of the list by moving items up or down. I could use any gnome/mate/cinnamon/etc file browsers too, if I had them installed).  You can even edit the list with your favourite text editor (again, the exact location of the file to edit varies according to which desktop environment you're using - on my system, it's `/home/cas/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`)

As with most things related to linux desktops, bookmarks are documented on freedesktop.org's web site.  See [desktop-bookmark-spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-bookmark-spec/).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I use xfce4 as well!